# Can't Disable Apple Remote

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, remote-control

I'm not sure why this is, but my Apple remote won't obey the decoupling set in System Preferences (see the pic below). This is important because I have an Apple TV 2, and there are times where my MacBook Pro is between me and the ATV2. Using the remote starts up iTunes, which means I have to manually stop iTunes and move the laptop to keep it from happening again. I do use the Apple iPhone/iPad Remote app, but there are times when I need to use the physical remote, which is when I have this problem. Anyone else observe this behavior?

[image: system prefs pic]

Side note: I used to have the [Candleair](http://www.iospirit.com/labs/candelair/) preference pane installed, but I purged the support files when I removed it. I initially thought that it might be some "stuck" leftover preference running in the background, but that's not the case.

Running 10.8.2 on a Late 2008 MBP.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. I think it is just a bug in OSX because I haven't seen anything online that has helped.